# How to add a column to CSV file and Import it into Powershell Hash

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, hash

I'm customizing a Powershell script (that checks windows event logs for specific EventID's) that does an Import-CSV of a 2 column CSV file into an array/hash.

It works fine AS-IS, (obviously) -- however, I want to **add a 3rd column** of values to the CSV file -- but when this causes the script to not work correctly even though I think I've modified the original code correctly.

Luckily, the script only references the hash in 2 places so maybe someone can point out whats wrong.

**Hash Instantiated with 2-Column CSV:**

```
$event_list = @{} 
Import-Csv event_log_check_events.csv |% {$event_list[$_.source + '#' + $_.id] = 1}
```

**Hash Used during Event Log Search:** **UPDATED**

```
if ($useinstanceid){ 
$log_hits = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName $log -Newest $n | Where-Object { $_.Message -like "*$message*" } |
? {$event_list[$_.source + "#" + $_.instanceid]} 
} 

else {$log_hits = Get-EventLog -ComputerName $server -LogName $log -Newest $n | Where-Object { $_.Message -like "*$message*" } |
? {$event_list[$_.source + "#" + $_.eventid]} 
}
```

**What I *tried* to do:**

```
$event_list = @{} 
Import-Csv event_log_check_events.csv |% {$event_list[$_.source + '#' + $_.id + '#' + $_.newcolumn] = 1}
```

**CSV (original):**

```
Source,ID
Source1,ID1
Source2,ID2
```

**CSV (modified):**

```
Source,ID,Newcolumn
Source1,ID1,newvalue1
Source2,ID2,newvalue2
```

Comment: Your "Hash Used during Event Log Search:" seems to be missing some code.

Comment: I second what @zdan says, and also would like to know what the behavioral differences between before and after your changes?

Comment: Original post has been updated.  Please take a look!